# How to separate wheels and body from and imported car model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to use the RBC addon to animate a car model. To do this, I first must separate the wheels from the car body. I've tried several ideas to do this and also searched the net for a tutorial with no luck. Can someone point me to a tutorial on how to perform the separation?

Comment: It depends whether each wheel was originally modelled in seperate parts (tyre, wheel rim, etc.) as to how easy it will be to seperate them. Start by going into Edit mode and deselecting all by clicking away from the model Then select a vertex on one of the tyres and hit Ctrl-L. If you're lucky this should hilight the wheel and tyre in one go. Then hit 'P' (Seperate) Selection. Back in Object mode you'll now have a separate wheel object. Do this for the other 3 wheels. If the parts of the wheel were modelled separately you'll just have to seperate each part in turn and join them with Ctrl-J.

Comment: @JohnEason: i think this is an answer - not a comment ;)

Comment: @Chris That was written just as I was about to go to bed. I didn't have a model available to compose a full answer with images at the time! :^)